# How to crop based on scaled dimensions?

Tags: imageresizer

Is there a way to scale an image down in size by say, 50 percent, and crop the scaled output? I've been tinkering with this, but it seems that any cropping is based on the original image dimensions rather than the scaled dimensions.

Comment: Cropping can also be done by percent - use `cropxunits=100&cropyunits=100`.

Answer (score 0):

### Cropping by percentage:

`?crop=20,20,80,80&cropxunits=100&cropyunits=100`

### Cropping by the output size:

`?width=400&height=300&crop=80,60,320,240&cropxunits=400&cropyunits=300`